# Add list of dataframes (of length n) to dataframe with n rows, R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

This is such a basic question, but I am stuck:
The code is taken from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/list-of-dataframes-in-r/

I have this list of dataframes of length 2.

```
# Create dataframe
df1 = data.frame(
  y1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  y2 = c(4, 5, 6)
)

# Create another dataframe
df2 = data.frame(
  y1 = c(7, 8, 9),
  y2 = c(1, 4, 6)
)

# Create list of data frame using list()
listOfDataframe = list(df1, df2)
```

Now I want that this list becomes a column in a `data.frame`. As my list is of length 2, I thought the dataframe should have two rows as I want each dataframe to be essentially on one row.
So I try the following:

```
df_list_col = data.frame(a = 1:2, listOfDataframe)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(a = 1:2, listOfDataframe) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Wrap the list in `I`: `d = data.frame(I(listOfDataframe))`; `str(d)`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This also works, I just do not understand why this is necessary

Comment: If you just do the ```data.frame(listOfDataframe)```then you see that the data.frame has 3 rows and 4 columns, what you try to do is adding "a" with 2 rows to that. The list length is not important here, but the number of rows of the data.frames in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Break it down in two steps -

```
df <- data.frame(a = seq_along(listOfDataframe))
df$b <- listOfDataframe

df
#  a                b
#1 1 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
#2 2 7, 8, 9, 1, 4, 6

df$b
#[[1]]
#  y1 y2
#1  1  4
#2  2  5
#3  3  6

#[[2]]
#  y1 y2
#1  7  1
#2  8  4
#3  9  6
```

---

Using `tibble` works directly -

```
tibble::tibble(a = seq_along(listOfDataframe), b = listOfDataframe)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     a b           
#  <int> <list>      
#1     1 <df [3 × 2]>
#2     2 <df [3 × 2]>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You have any idea why it is like this?

Comment: I think the accepted answer in the linked post explains it.